# PHP Mysql Duplicate Entry Error for Unique Column

Tags: mysql

I have a ton of data I have to parse and insert into a mysql database.

Some of it is duplicate, so I setup a unique index on the column that needs to be unique.

Instead of running the insert queries 1 by 1, I'm doing batches of 100 to lessen the load on the DB. However if I get a duplicate entry error, it seems that entire batch is not inserted. Is there a way to structure the query to say "if there are duplicates ignore those but please insert the rest of the data"?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the IGNORE keyword for that:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert.html